# BizTalk SFTP Receive Location Error

Tags: biztalk, sftp

I got this SFTP Receive Location error despite that SFTP send port working fine with the same configuration.

> The Messaging Engine failed to add a receive location "SFTP Receive Location" with URL "sftp://10.40.100.20:22/In/*.xml" to the adapter "SFTP". Reason: "Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.SftpInvoker.SftpException: List remote directory error.
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.SftpInvoker.SftpInvoker.ListRemoteDirectory(String dirname)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Sftp.SftpRLConfig.ValidateConfiguration(SftpReceivePropertyBag receivePropertyBag)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Sftp.SftpRLConfig.CreateBinding(RHConfig rhConfig)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.BtsServiceHostBase.InitializeRuntime()
>          at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostBase.OnOpen(TimeSpan timeout)
>          at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.Open(TimeSpan timeout)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiveEndpoint.Enable()
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiveEndpoint..ctor(BizTalkEndpointContext endpointContext, IBTTransportProxy transportProxy, ControlledTermination control)
>          at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfReceiver`2.AddReceiveEndpoint(String url, IPropertyBag adapterConfig, IPropertyBag bizTalkConfig)".

Answer (score 0):

**List remote directory error.**
It looks like it doesn't have the rights to list the contents of the remote directory.
Check that the account that BizTalk is using to connect has the rights to list the contents of the directory.

Comment: i did and i have all the permission to read write delete files

Comment: Yes, but that does not include the rights to LIST FILES.  That is what is missing and what it is complaining about.